# Ruby on Rails plural (controller) and singular (model) convention - explanation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As per Ruby on Rails convention, controller names get pluralized while model names are singular. Example : a Users controller, but a User model.

```
rails generate controller Users
rails generate model User name:string email:string
```

Now open migration file

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email    
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here table name is plural (users).

So my question is - Why table name is plural (users) even though the model name is singular (User)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Ruby on Rails follow **linguistic convention**. That means a model represents a single user, 
whereas a database table consists of many users.

Comment: So what's the story for non-standard pluralizations?  For instance, if my model were "Activity", would the table end up being "Activities" or "Activitys"?

Comment: It would be "Activities" the rails helper method "pluralize" is very clever. It knows that the plural of 'person' is 'people', and so on. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize

Comment: Does the Rails model pluralization convention assume models are written in English?

Answer (score 13):

An instance of your `User` model represents a single user, so is singular. The `users` table, by contrast, holds all of your users, so it's plural.

Answer (score 4):

To complete Emily's answer

> An instance of your User model represents a single user, so is singular. The users table, by contrast, holds all of your users, so it's plural.

Answer (score 1):

in rails conntroller and table name are plural model alone is singular.In a two word name second word is pluralized !

Answer (score 0):

Because the table holds users. Its just the convention.