# Instantiating an associated model input is available to populate the model attributes (has_one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to, has-one

What is the right way to create a data model object so that I can create a form. When I first create the object it doesn't have params data with the valid attribute data so the build_ returns an invalid object and rails throws 500 Internal Server Error.

Here's what I'm looking at:

**Models**

```
class Credentials < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to user
...
class User < Active ::Base
has_one :credentials, :dependent => :destroy
...
```

**Controller**

```
def new
@cred = current_user.build_credentials 
    render 'edit'
end
    ...
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@cred) do |f| %>
```

**Log**

```
Started GET "/credentials" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-16 00:43:26 -0500
Processing by CredentialsController#new as HTML
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`remember_token` = 'oWGXC2dmcg2sRyg5mvA6fw' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCredentials Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT `credentials`.* FROM `credentials` WHERE `credentials`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered credentials/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (8.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 100ms
```

**rsec results**

```
undefined method `credentials_index_path' for #<#<Class:...
```

The credentials model has many verification requirements so the object that is being created by `new` is invalid (I can confirm this in the console) as the only value that is populated is the foreign key, in this case user_id. However in the console I can establish the @credentials variable and the in the next command assign all the attributes. In the web server the 500 error makes it impossible to follow the same approach.

**Update**
To make this more clear, the problem is that the `@cred = current_user.build_credentials` is returning a nil.
I put an `raise @cred.inspect` call directly after creating @cred to validate that its nil. When I get to the view `form_for(@cred)...` @cred is just a nil object so it pukes with `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Credentials belongs to controller? It should belongs to user, and if you use `has_one` association, you should use singular noun of credential:

**Model**

```
class Credential < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to user
...
class User < Active ::Base
has_one :credential, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Controller**

In your controller, if you want create new object for form, you only need:

```
def new
  @cred = current_user.build_credential 
end

def create
  @cred = current_user.build_credential(params[:cred])
  if @cred.save
    # what you do when creating object success
  else
    # what you do when creating object failed
  end
end
```

**View**

In your `new.html.erb` in `app/views/credentials/` folder, create your form:

```
<%= form_for @cred do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

To link to `new.html.erb` page, in your view create a `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'New Credential', new_credential_path %>
```

**Routes**

If you want to use RESTful route, In your `routes.rb`, add resources for credential you don't have:

```
resources :credentials
```

Comment: Yes `belongs_to user` is correct, i fixed the original post. Fatigue induced typo. Sorry about that.

Comment: working on it...currently getting the error when rendering `credentials/new.html.erb within layouts/application `

Comment: in your body element of your `application.html.erb`, do you have `<%= yield %>`?

Comment: I don't understand why @cred is nil since we instantiated it in in credentials#new with `@cred=current_user.build_credentials`. The error message is `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
`      Also In your answer you use the method build_credential (no s) and every where else you use credentials (with s). My controller/model is called credentials (with s)

Comment: The problem, I have discovered, is in the naming of my classes/models. Your code works, thanks. I incorrectly had pluralized my model names. This post helped me see the light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078139/ruby-on-rails-plural-controller-and-singular-model-convention-explanation

Comment: ahh, i saw it, `class Credential`, i edited my answer, thanks for accept :)