# I need explanation of method inject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to figure out how inject method works

Can someone explain this

```
def mysort
  if djeca.any?
      djeca.order(name: :asc).inject([]) { |sum, c| sum += c.mysort}.uniq
  else
      [self]
end
```

`mysort` is method of model  class  `Books`

In controller I call method mysort :

```
@mybooks= Books.find_by(name: 'renesansa')
@mybookss= @mybooks.leaf_wms
```

Comment: http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/06/23/using-select-reject-collect-inject-and-detect This link has good explanation

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

Comment: Is the model Books really a collection of Books, or just one Book?
Model should have a singular name. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078139/ruby-on-rails-plural-controller-and-singular-model-convention-explanation

Comment: Hi. Your question is likely being downvoted because it does not show that you researched or attempted to research the topic. (It looks like you skipped searching altogether and asked us.) A question ought to show that you devoted some effort prior to reaching out for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
djeca.order(name: :asc).inject([]) { |sum, c| sum += c.mysort}.uniq
```

is equivalent to

```
sum = []
djeca.order(name: :asc).each{|c| sum = sum + c.mysort}
sum.uniq
```

Adding arrays is actually [concatening](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2B), so your code just appends all the c.mysort into an array.

If I understand it correctly, you could also write :

```
djeca.order(name: :asc).map{|c| c.mysort}.flatten.uniq
```

Depending on your audience, you might want to write one or the other.
Note that you don't need to assign a value to sum in the inject block, it is done automatically.

```
(1..10).inject(0){|mem,i| mem += i}
#=> 55

(1..10).inject(0){|mem,i| mem + i}
#=> 55
```

Comment: tnx for your reply, I don't understand this part  c.mysort   in method mysort we call method mysort . Is that recursion ?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this link https://samurails.com/tips/ruby-ruby-on-rails-inject/

For example:

```
result = [1,2,3,4].inject(0) { |sum, number| sum + number }
```

Here, the process starts from `0` index to the `3` index. First inject adds `1 & 2` to get the sum of two values and stored in `sum` variable(i.e. sum= 3) and then it takes the `sum` value and adds 3 to it, to get result(i.e sum=6) and so on. Finally you will get the result like `10`.

Answer (score 0):

> djeca.order(name: :asc)

Retrieves array of active records

> .inject([])

Looping through each active record. The initial output of inject is empty array [].

> { |sum, c| }

c - each active record

sum - Inject output value. Initially its []. On each iteration the value is appended to the array. (**sum += [some values]**)